# Redirect con React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

Estoy implementando un login mediante API REST con php, jwt y react para el frontend, el problema es que después de hacer login quiero enviar a la siguiente pagina usando `<Redirect to='/path'>` pero no consigo que funcione este es mi componente para el login

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


import "../../css/pages/pages.css";
import "../../css/pages/login-register-lock.css";

import FormLogin from "./FormLogin";
import Error from "../Error";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      login: false,
      error: false,
      type_error: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token") !== null) {
      this.setState({
        login: true
      });
      // const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
      // this.get_perfil_info(token.data);
    }
  }

  login = user_info => {
    // si se envio el formulario no vacio
    if (user_info.username !== "" && user_info.password !== "") {
      this.setState({
        error: false,
        type_error: ""
      });

      if (this.state.login) {
        // redirect
      }

    } else {
      this.setState({
        error: true,
        login: false,
        type_error: "empty"
      });
    }
  };

  api_login = login_info => {
    const form_data = new FormData();

    form_data.append("email", login_info.username);
    form_data.append("password", login_info.password);

    axios
      .post("http://api.local.labtak:88/sysuser/login", form_data)
      .then(response => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({
          login: true
        });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          error: true,
          login: false,
          type_error: "login"
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const error = this.state.error;
    const type_error = this.state.type_error;
    let resultado;
    if (error) {
      switch (type_error) {
        case "login":
          resultado = <Error mensaje="Usuario o contraseña erroneos" />;
          break;
        case "empty":
          resultado = <Error mensaje="Ambos campos son requeridos" />;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    return (
      <section id="wrapper">
        <div className="login-register">
          <div className="login-box card">
            <div className="card-body">
              {resultado}
              <FormLogin login={this.login} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Y estas son las rutas que estoy usando

```
//Dependencias
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

// componentes
import Login from './Login/Login'
import UpdateUser from './Update/UpdateUser'
class AppRouter extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            is_logged: false
        }
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render= { () => (
                        <Login/> 
                    )}/>
                    <Route path="/update" render={ () => (
                        <UpdateUser/>
                    ) } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Dentro del componente App tengo solo esto:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import AppRouter from './Router'

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <AppRouter />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes proveer una función a tu componente de logueo que sea capaz de pasar el cambio de estado de inicio de sesión desde dentro de el, hasta el componente AppRouter modificando la propiedad is_logged, y posteriormente a esto, validar dentro del Switch que tienes si es necesario o no redireccionar.

```js
class AppRouter extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            is_logged: false
        }

        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this)
    }

    handleLogin(is_logged) {
        this.setState({is_logged})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render= { () => (
                        this.state.is_logged 
                            ? <Redirect from="/" to="/update" />
                            : <Login onLogin={this.handleLogin} /> 
                    )}/>
                    <Route path="/update" render={ () => (
                        <UpdateUser/>
                    ) } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfecto

Comment: con gusto amigo

Comment: por cierto, recuerda validar también que cuando ingrese a las otras rutas deba estar logueado o te redireccione a la de logueo

Comment: si claro ya lo considere estoy justo validando eso gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer algo más escalable te recomeindo hacer esto:

```js
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Y luego lo usas así:

```js
<PrivateRoute path="/protected">
  <ProtectedPage />
</PrivateRoute>
```

Ejemplo completo acá en la página oficial de react router:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow